# Rerunning a code in python using loops

Tags: python

I am new to python, and recently I came across a problem. The problem asked to write a code that will select the lowest monthly payment rate so that by year end, the balance is 0 or negative.

The plan to tackle this problem is to 1st assume a value for the monthly payment, and then find the balance at the end of the year, also taking account of the interest per month. And then, write code to compare the balance to 0 or negative. If there is still a positive value for balance, then the code will add 10 to the monthly payment and keep repeating until balance is 0 or negative.

pasted is my code. I can think of the logic behind it, but my code stops everytime when the month is 12, and it cannot go on, and I don't know how to ask the code to rerun the calculation.

```
balance = 3329
a = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthly_interest_rate = (annualInterestRate)/12.0

monthlyPaymentRate = 10

month = 1
total = 0

while (month < 13):
    monthly_unpaid_balance = (balance) - (monthlyPaymentRate)
    updated_balance_each_month = (monthly_unpaid_balance) + (monthly_interest_rate * monthly_unpaid_balance)
    round (updated_balance_each_month,2)
    unpaid= updated_balance_each_month
    month = month + 1
    balance=unpaid
    total = total + balance

    if (total >0 ):
        balance=a
        monthlyPaymentRate=monthlyPaymentRate+ 10
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset your month to 1 in your if statement that checks `if (unpaid > 0)` but you also need to check `if(month == 13)`. On top of that you are setting `a` to `balance` each time you loop. Try this

```
balance = 3329
a=balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthly_interest_rate= (annualInterestRate)/12.0
monthlyPaymentRate=10

month=1
total=0
unpaid = 1

while unpaid > 0:

     monthly_unpaid_balance = (balance) - (monthlyPaymentRate)
     unpaid = round((monthly_unpaid_balance + monthly_interest_rate * monthly_unpaid_balance), 2)
     #Your round line doesn't do anything since it returns the new answer but you don't assign it to anything. That being said, it's an unnecessary line and will work without the rounding


     month += 1
     balance=unpaid
     total += monthlyPaymentRate


     if (unpaid > 0 and month == 13):
         balance=a
         monthlyPaymentRate += 10
         month = 1

print(monthlyPaymentRate)
```

I think that is what you're asking for. So what it does is that it checks the unpaid amount only on the last month. If it is greater than zero and it has gone through all 12 months then it resets the balance back to the original with `balance = a` adds `10` to the `monthlyPaymentRate` and resets the month back to `1`. If it's less than zero then it will break out of the while loop and print the `monthlyPaymentRate`

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I wish I could translate my thoughts into code as well you do. Your code makes sense, but the expected output is 310, while yours is 280. I am trying to find out where is the mistake.

Comment: @KeenanKon I made a guess on the calculation since it was missing an operation and I also made a mistake in my if statement. updated. Also if this fixed your problem then don't forget to upvote and mark this as your accepted answer